# Compositum of normal extensions is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I found the following statement on the Wikipedia page for normal extensions:

> Let *L* be an extension of a field *K*. Then:
>
> If *E* and *F* are  normal extensions of *K* contained in *L*, then the compositum *EF* is also a normal extension of *K*.

This question has previously been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287923/compositum-of-normal-extensions-is-a-normal-extension), but the answer made use of the characterisation of normal extensions that involves automorphisms on *EF*.

I'd like to prove the statement directly from an equivalent definition of normal extensions (stated below), but I've only been successful for the case where *E* and *F* are also finite extensions of *K*.

> *L* is a normal extension of *K* if every irreducible polynomial in *K*[*X*] that has a root in *L* actually splits over *L*.

Answer (score 2):

You said you've been successful in the case that $E$ and $F$ are finite, but the general case follows immediately from that case.  If $x\in EF$, then $x$ is in the subfield of $L$ generated by finitely many elements of $E$ and $F$.  Let $E_0\subseteq E$ be the splitting field of the minimal polynomials of those finitely many elements of $E$ and similarly define $F_0\subseteq F$.  Then $E_0$ and $F_0$ are finite and normal over $K$, and $x\in E_0F_0$.  But then $E_0F_0$ is normal over $K$, so the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$ splits over $E_0F_0$.  The minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$ thus splits over $EF$.  Since $x\in EF$ was arbitrary, $EF$ is normal over $K$.