# Compositum of normal extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

Given two normal (finite) extensions $E_1,E_2$ of $F$, such that $E_1,E_2 \subseteq \bar{F}$, prove that $E_1E_2 = \{\sum_{i=1}^d e_1e_2: e_1 \in E_1, e_2 \in E_2, d>0\}$ is normal.

I see the answer of [Compositum of normal extensions is a normal extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287923/compositum-of-normal-extensions-is-a-normal-extension). But why does $\sigma(KM) = \sigma(K)\sigma(M)$? An element in $KM$ is not a single product but finite sum of products.

But **more importantly**, can we prove this statement without using that characterization? Answer in [Compositum of normal extensions is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521202/compositum-of-normal-extensions-is-normal) only prove infinite case assuming the finite case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E_1E_2 $ is the smallest subfield of $\overline {F} $ which contains elements of both $E_1$ and $E_2$. Thus any element of $E_1E_2 $ is made using elements of $E_1,E_2$ using field operations. So an arbitrary element of $E_1E_2 $ can be written as $$\left. \sum_{i=1}^m a_ib_i\middle/\sum_{i=1}^n c_id_i\right.\tag{1} $$ where $a_i, c_i\in E_1$ and $b_i,d_i\in E_2$. Now the denominator here contains $2n$ variables and each of them is a root of some irreducible polynomial in $F[x] $. Here we use the fact that the extensions $E_1/F,E_2/F$ are finite and hence algebraic.

Thus assuming these variables are roots of irreducible polynomials of degrees $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_{2n}$ we can observe that their conjugates also lie in same field. In other words cionjugates of $c_i$ lie in $E_1$ while those of $d_i$ lie in $E_2$. Thus we can replace each variable in denominator with its conjugate and multiply the denominator with such expressions. Finally the denominator will consist of a product of $$k_1k_2\dots k_{2n}$$ such expressions (the first of which is already the denominator of $(1)$). We need to use the same expressions except the first one to multiply the numerator of $(1)$ also so that the fraction does not change. The denominator is now a symmetric function of $c_i, d_i$  and their conjugates and hence belongs to $F$.

The numerator on the other hand is a product of linear combinations of elements of $E_1,E_2$ and hence the overall expression can be written in the form $$\sum_{i=1}^p e_if_i$$ where $e_i\in E_1,f_i\in E_2$. Moreover any expression of above form lies in $E_1E_2 $ as it is made up of elements of $E_1,E_2$ using sums and products.

---

Next we show that $E_1E_2 $ is normal over $F$. It is better to use the property that if $\sigma$ is an automorpshism of $\overline {F} $ which fixes $F$ then we have $$\sigma (E_1)\subseteq E_1,\sigma(E_2)\subseteq E_2\tag{1}$$ Next let us apply $\sigma$ on any arbitrary element $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$ (where $a_i\in E_1,b_i\in E_2$) of $E_1E_2 $ to get $$\sigma(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma(a_i)\sigma(b_i)$$ and the right hand side lies in $E_1E_2$ because $\sigma(a_i) \in E_1,\sigma(b_i)\in E_2$. Thus applying $\sigma$ on any arbitrary element of $E_1E_2 $ gives us another element of $E_1E_2 $. This means that $$\sigma(E_1E_2) \subseteq E_1E_2 $$ and this holds for any arbitrary automorphism $\sigma$ of $\overline {F} $ which fixes $F$. Thus $E_1E_2 $ is also normal over $F$.